# Connect to Redis database using Deno

Tags: typescript, redis, deno

So I'm using Deno for my server and I want to persist some data in a Redis database, how can I do it?

I tried to follow this documentation (https://deno.land/x/redis) but didn't quite understand, I know Redis offers a lot of services, and this is my first time using it, so I'm a little confused

Answer (score 1):

use `connect` to connect to your Redis server. Then use `.set` method to set a value, equivalent to redis command:

```
SET key value
```

And use `.get` to retrieve the value, which is equivalent to redis command:

```
GET key
```

```js
import { connect } from "https://denopkg.com/keroxp/deno-redis/mod.ts";
const redis = await connect({
  hostname: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 6379
});

const ok = await redis.set("deno", "land");
const value = await redis.get("deno");

console.log(value) // deno
```

Run the script using `--allow-net` flag:

```
deno run --allow-net redis.js
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { connect } from "https://denopkg.com/keroxp/deno-redis/mod.ts";
const redis = await connect({
    hostname: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 6379
});
await redis.set("user1", "Nikhil");
await redis.set("user2", "Mahesh");

const users = await redis.keys("user*");
console.log(users);
```

Make sure if you get `Uncaught PermissionDenied: network access to "127.0.0.1:6379", run again with the --allow-net flag` privilege error, you are missing `--allow-net` flag while running.

> deno run --allow-net server.ts